# How to apply functions on a cell after fetching data from VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data map

```
Channel Value Transformation Coefficient
a       10    LN(Log)             0.1
b       20    ^(Squared)         0.2
```

I'm using VLOOKUP to generate some data where I need to apply these transformations to a value of one cell so e.g.

```
Channel Metric TransformedVal
a       100    =LN(100)
a       200    =LN(200)
b       200    =200^2
```

Not sure if we can do this directly with VLOOKUP. Any pointers?

Comment: what function and is there any link between the two tables you used?

Comment: what is the relationship of coefficient to the formula? I guess what you are doing is vlookup of formula to be used?

Comment: @krib The only link is the Channel field and I can use that to fetch the name of the transformation (say LN) but how do I apply this to a cell in the second table

Comment: @JemEripol Well, no..The coefficient value would be applied to the value obtained from TransformedVal field so that's not a concern as I can simply get the value from VLOOKUP and multiply it with the cell from TransformedVal

Comment: Are you not allowed to use macros?

Comment: @JemEripol Not much experience there. Might have to go that route if there's no alternative

Comment: You should try macros. It is way easier if you do it there because you can just loop through the function to check. So there will be no vlookup anymore.

Comment: You can try using Evaluate function, more here https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function

Comment: I would agree with AntiDrondert that Evaluate is perferct for that. No VBA, user defined functions so no coding is necessary... Also I just checked and it works even in Excel 2016 and is fairly easy to implement. You just need to use the named range "override", but that is no big deal.

Comment: @Pavel_V Could you please elucidate

Answer (score 0):

When you read the link that AntiDrondert posted my answer will seem much clearer :-) It simply states that excel has Evaluate formula which is designed to take text string and evaluate it as if it was formula, but as it is there only because of compatibility purposes you cant really use it as normal formula. However, you can still use it in Named ranges. So you only need to create a named range with text string of what you want to have calculated.
In this case you need to have LN(...) and (...)^2 added to the formula. So you know you need to add something before as well as after the cell reference (the Metric). So split the needed formula into two parts - one that goes before the cell reference, the second that goes after the cell reference. For the "LN(...)" it would be "LN(" and ")" and store these values in columns next to your first table. For the squared I used "(" and ")^2" although the brackets are not necessary I guess. Then create the named range where you concatenate the vlookup of the first part of the formula based on Channel, cell reference and vlookup of the second part of the formula. All inside Evaluate function. (make sure you dont fix rows for the cell reference and vlookup value). See pic below. As you can see on the picture I get the same results using this method as you have in the example and without vba.

```
=EVALUATE(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$J2;Sheet1!$A:$F;5;FALSE)&Sheet1!$K2&VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$J2;Sheet1!$A:$F;6;FALSE))
```

[image: Evaluate_example]